# PyMongo - Select object from an array having max value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

A document in my DB looks like this :

```
 {
    "_id": ObjectId("5e92e63fad262707ff301d6c"),
    "uknum": 30,
    "area": "bath",
    "ukelectors": 62355,
    "ukresults": [
      {
        "party": "con",
        "leader": "thatcher",
        "ukvotes": 22544
      },
      {
        "party": "lab",
        "leader": "foot",
        "ukvotes": 7259
      },
      {
        "party": "sdp",
        "leader": "jenkins",
        "ukvotes": 17240
      },
      {
        "party": "eco",
        "leader": "whittaker",
        "ukvotes": 441
      }
    ]
  }
```

**Requirement :**

I need to build a query in python to get the name of the party which won `area: bath`. Basically, check who got maximum votes and choose that party.

The idea was to use [$max](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) aggregation pipeline but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using either one of the [aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) query :

**Query 1 :** Without use of `$unwind`, by using `$reduce` on array :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { area: "bath" } },
  {
    $addFields: {
      ukresults: {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            res: {
              $reduce: {
                input: "$ukresults",
                initialValue: { votes: 0, party: {} },
                in: {
                  votes: {
                    $cond: [
                      { $gt: ["$$this.ukvotes", "$$value.votes"] },
                      "$$this.ukvotes",
                      "$$value.votes",
                    ],
                  },
                  party: {
                    $cond: [
                      { $gt: ["$$this.ukvotes", "$$value.votes"] },
                      "$$this",
                      "$$value.party",
                    ],
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
          in: "$$res.party",
        },
      },
    },
  },
]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JItjDR5VCzG)

**Query 2 :** With use of `$unwind` :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      area: "bath"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$ukresults",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "ukresults.ukvotes": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gMNTSa6ggpc)

I would say these two might perform well as we're doing on mostly one document (Cause we've `$match` as first stage), maybe first query might take a wile to iterate if you've more elements in array, give it a try & choose one which helps most.

**Ref :** Check this pymongo documentation for aggregation examples : [pymongo-aggregation](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/aggregation.html).

Answer (score 0):

The following aggregation query prints the `ukresults` sub-document with maximum votes.

The aggregation operator `$max` cannot be applied directly on the `ukresults` array, as the array has sub-documents rather than scalar values, like numbers. So, we use `$reduce` aggregation operator to extract the sub-document with maximum votes. Note that using the `$reduce` operator is a *reduction operation* on an array, so is using `$max` - the difference is the array element data type.

*The PyMongo code:*

```
import pymongo
import pprint
client = pymongo.MongoClient()
collection = client.test.testCollection

pipeline = [
  { 
      "$match": { "area": "bath" } 
  },
  { 
      "$addFields": {
          "maxvotes": {
              "$reduce": {
                  "input": "$ukresults",
                  "initialValue": { "ukvotes": 0  },
                  "in": {
                      "$cond": [
                          { "$gt": [ "$$this.ukvotes", "$$value.ukvotes"] }, 
                                       "$$this",
                                       "$$value"
                      ]
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  },
  { 
      "$project": {
          "_id": 0,
          "area": 1,
          "maxvotes": 1
      }
  }
]

pprint.pprint(list(collection.aggregate(pipeline)))
```

*The output:*

```
[{'area': 'bath',
  'maxvotes': {'leader': 'thatcher', 'party': 'con', 'ukvotes': 22544.0}}]
```